# How many joules are required to mine a unit of coal?

Tags: mining, economic-geology, coal

Coal is still a major source of energy for generation of electricity. So how much energy is used to extract a unit (tonne/kilogram etc) of coal? And thus what is the efficiency of coal as a source of energy?

Comment: The answer would vary by country and mining method. Strip vs. longwall vs. drift vs. slope vs. mountaintop vs. open-pit... Do you use many Chinese miners or mighty German [Baggers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bagger_293)?

Comment: Also the coal deposit. Eg. quality of coal, is it heavily faulted, geological location, etc.

Comment: Given my lack of knowledge about mining/ coal types I'm looking for a best case / worst case scenario. The man vs mechanical power is an interesting one - in terms of energy efficiency is it better to use a massive machine or a mass of people!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The efficiency of coal as a source of electricity is very low: typically of the order of 30%. So losses are of the order of 70%. But losses due to energy expended in the extraction of the coal itself only form a very small proportion of this.

Estimates for extractive losses tend to be [of the order of 0.5-5%](http://dx.doi.org/10.3390/su3101796). That's a huge relative range, because the energy density of different types of coal (J/kg) can vary by a factor of 5; the coal could come from a deep mine or an open-cast; and the amount and kind of mechanisation varies hugely.

But these huge *relative* variations are completely swamped in *absolute* terms by the other losses, which are at the very best 20%, and can be 65% or so. Which is why there's not a huge amount of literature on the energy inputs to coal extraction: it's such a small part of total losses, that it gets lost in the rounding.

In the British residential electricity supply, there's about 7% losses from local distribution (UK figure), 2-3% from transmission grid, and about 60% losses at the plant itself, in the form of heat (NB efficiencies here are multiplicative, rather than additive). The British average for 2013 was 64.2% losses in plant - see [DUKES 2014](https://www.gov.uk/government/statistics/electricity-chapter-5-digest-of-united-kingdom-energy-statistics-dukes) table 5.9

CHP plants mitigate this by capturing a large share of the heat, for distribution in local heat grids. But they still have losses of 5-25% at the plant itself, and then further losses in the heat and electricity distribution system. Call it 20% losses in the best case. Denmark has a lot of high-efficiency coal plants and CHP, but still only managed 55% efficiency, so 45% losses (Danish Electricity Supply '08 Statistical Survey, Table 10).